# Prove that $f(x)=e^x$ is Riemann integrable using Riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Does anyone know how to prove that $f(x)=e^x$ is Riemann integrable using right or left hand Riemann sums?

Comment: if you want to do it directly, split your interval into pieces of equal length $\epsilon$, and the upper and lower Riemann sums are both geometrical series, with the upper one $e^\epsilon$-times bigger than the lower one

Answer (score 9):

If the goal is simply to show $e^x$ is integrable on some interval $[a,b]$ (as opposed to actually computing the value of the integral), it's not even necessary to sum the geometric series.  Since $e^x$ is increasing, the left-hand sum is a lower sum ($L$) and the right-hand sum is an upper sum ($U$) and so the difference $U-L$ (if we use a uniform partition) is given by 
$$ U-L = \frac{b-a}{n} (e^b - e^a).
$$ 
This is less than any $\epsilon > 0$ for suitable choice of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$e^x$ uniformly continuous in every interval $[a,b]$. Explicitly, $|e^x-e^y|\le e^b |x-y|$ for $x,y\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

WLOG take the range of integration $[0,b]$. Then then the left-hand Riemann sum is given by
$$\text{LH} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{j b/N}=\frac{e^b -1}{e^{b/N}-1}.$$
The right-hand sum can also be obtained
$$\text{RH} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{j b/N}=e^{b/N}\, \text{LH}.$$ For $b$ constant and $N\to\infty$, 
$$ \text{RH} = \text{LH} = e^b-1$$
which proves that $e^x$ is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is easily handled if you use one of the *Riemann integrability theorems* for continuous or for monotone functions.

Otherwise, if you really have to check integrability through the definition, you can do as follows.

Take an interval $[a,b]$ and a decomposition $D=\{ a=x_0<x_1\ldots <x_n<x_{n+1}=b\} \subseteq [a,b]$ of the interval; write explicitly the values of:

$s_D(e^x)= \sum_{k=0}^n \inf_{x\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]} e^x\ (x_{k+1}-x_k)$ and

$S_D(e^x)= \sum_{k=0}^n \sup_{x\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]} e^x\ (x_{k+1}-x_k)$;

then consider $S_D(e^x)-s_D(e^x)$ and prove that this difference can be bounded from above by small $\varepsilon >0$ uniformly w.r.t. $D$ (i.e. uniformly w.r.t. the number of point of $D$) as long as $D$ has small diameter $\delta :=\max \{ x_{k+1} -x_k| k=0,\ldots ,n\}$, in the sense that $\delta<C \varepsilon$. In order to properly choose $\delta$, you have to use the [hint of lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28884/prove-that-fx-ex-is-riemann-integrable-using-riemann-sums/28888#28888).